# Trying to split a query into sections of six

Tags: php

I have a query which returns all custom post, I'm trying to split all post into sections of six then wrap them in an list item.

Right now its performing as it should but breaks when it get to the 12 post, their are a total of 40 post. Im not sure what wrong could someone help.

```
<?php 

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'posts_per_page' => -1                
        );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php if($count === 1 ): echo "<li>"; endif; ?>

    <?php if($count % 7 == 0 ): echo "<li>"; endif; ?>
     <div class="portfolio">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-large'); ?>
        <div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color:#fff;">more info</a>
    </div>

<?php if($count % 6 == 0 ): echo "</li>"; endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: The query is present i have just not includes it

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is correct but you're running into the "posts_per_page" problem.

In your query, use 'posts_per_page=-1' to return all posts (assuming that's what you want). I'm guessing your website is currently set to show 12 posts per page in the settings->reading area.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the [offset](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) property in the query e.g.

```
 $query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=6' ) );
 $query2 = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=6offset=6' ) );
```

You would basically do 2 queries, 6 posts in query 1, and then in query 2 do the 6 posts again but add an offset of 6, which will skip the first 6 posts so they aren't repeated.

Comment: I will give it a go later this evening

Comment: don't do additional queries for something that can be done entirely in php, you will use far more memory and cpu for each additional query.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that I had `wp_reset_query();` in the middle of my loop which was resitting the offset counter, also I changed

```
<?php if($count === 1 ): echo "<li>"; endif; ?>
<?php if($count % 7 == 0 ): echo "<li>"; endif; ?>
```

**to** `<?php if($count % 6 == 0 ): echo "<li>"; endif; ?>`

which fixed my issue.